# How to force load Disqus Comments in a Blogger 3rd party Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger, disqus

I have a blog in which I have a 3rd party theme installed. 
My blog is blogger blog
I do not have plans on changing the theme since the idea and how it's built 
matches my site contents.
What I wanted to ask is, there are sometimes that Disqus Comments do not load at all. Even if I refresh the page it doesn't load.

I want a code to force it to reload after checking it's not loaded. This doesn't happen only to Disqus but also to AddThis share buttons. I added `async='async'` to both the scripts to let it load a bit late. Though it increased the probability that it loads, still didn't change fact that it sometime doesn't load. And when that sometimes of not loading occurs, whether it loads sometimes after refresh or it never loads even after refresh(Unless I copy the link and open a new tab or window in browser and open the page again).

The blogger theme has also been installed with bootstrapper. 
So I had to wrap the `comment_picker` with `<div class='col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12' id='disqus_thread'>`
By the way, the `id='disqus_thread'` is something I put randomly but it still did increase the probability that it loads.

Here is the code for the disqus and `comment_picker` in the widget `Blog1`

**Comment picker**

```
<b:includable id='comment_picker' var='post'>
 <div class='col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12' id='disqus_thread'>
  <b:if cond='data:post.commentSource == 1'>
   <b:include data='post' name='iframe_comments'/>
    <b:elseif cond='data:post.showThreadedComments'/>
      <b:include data='post' name='threaded_comments'/>
    <b:else/>
  <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
 </b:if>
 </div>
</b:includable>
```

**Disqus**

```
<b:widget id='HTML1' locked='false' title='Disqus for site' type='HTML' version='1'>
  <b:widget-settings>
   <b:widget-setting name='content'><![CDATA[<!-- Disqus Widget -->]]>
   </b:widget-setting>
  </b:widget-settings>
<b:includable id='main'>
<script asyn='async' type='text/javascript'>
 var disqus_shortname = &#39;site&#39;;
 var disqus_blogger_current_url = &quot;<data:blog.canonicalUrl/>&quot;;
 if (!disqus_blogger_current_url.length) {
   disqus_blogger_current_url = &quot;<data:blog.url/>&quot;;
 }
 var disqus_blogger_homepage_url = &quot;<data:blog.homepageUrl/>&quot;;
 var disqus_blogger_canonical_homepage_url = &quot;
 <data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl/>&quot;;
 </script>
 <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
 <style type='text/css'>
 #comments {display:none;}
 </style>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
     (function() {
      var bloggerjs = document.createElement(&#39;script&#39;);
      bloggerjs.type = &#39;text/javascript&#39;;
      bloggerjs.async = true;
      bloggerjs.src = &#39;//&#39; + disqus_shortname + &#39;.disqus.com/blogger_item.js&#39;;
     (document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;head&#39;)[0] || 
    document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;body&#39;)[0]).appendChild(bloggerjs);
   })();
</script>
</b:if>
<style type='text/css'>
.post-comment-link { visibility: hidden; }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
var bloggerjs = document.createElement(&#39;script&#39;);
bloggerjs.type = &#39;text/javascript&#39;;
bloggerjs.async = true;
bloggerjs.src = &#39;//&#39; + disqus_shortname + &#39;.disqus.com/blogger_index.js&#39;;
(document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;head&#39;)[0] ||document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;body&#39;)[0]).appendChild(bloggerjs);
})();
</script>
</b:includable>
```

Link to my full theme : 
https://pastebin.com/WDMMZFfh

You can take some time but please try to solve it.

Comment: What is the output in the developer console, when the **disqus** doesn't load?

Answer (score 1):

Disqus widget must come after `Blog1` widget to detect div with `id='comments'` and because your theme doesn't show Blog1 widget in **Layout** page you can cut Disqus widget and paste it directly after `<b:widget id='Blog1'>...</b:widget>`

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot. I'll see for some days and report here if there is anymore problems.

Comment: BTW, I wanted to ask , though I won't implement it. How to make a widget show or not show in Blogger layout? Like how did the one who developed the theme hide the Blog1 Widget which is very important from showing up in layout?

Comment: And one more thing I wanted to know, how to widen the area of my blog. I want to cover up the spaces at left and right fully. I tried editing some `.container` but didn't get any favourable result.

Comment: To wide container area use id. add this code to CSS `#wrapper { width: 100%; }` and the Blog1 Widget doesn't appear in your layout because its section `main` is disabled in home page by the condition `<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
<div id='manga_post'/><div id='manga_nav'/>
<b:else/>
<b:section class='main' id='main'>....</b:if>` you can't change it here unless you have changed theme structure.